# Change page on GridView if edit row this return error

Tags: c#, gridview, pagination

I know this problem exist in stackoverflow. but mine is seems different. I don't see any problem. but it happens sometimes in runtime when changed page on gridview.

If working on first page of Gridview I don't have error on edit row in gridview.
If change page of Gridview and try for editing any row return error.

I'm trying to add data as one by one row to a datagridview here is my code and it says:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size
>   of the collection parameter name:index"

What does this means ? is there any problem in my code.

Line error :

> GridView g2 =
>   (GridView)gvProducts.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("GridView2");

Here is my code : Could anyone please see and tell me what happens?

```
protected void gvProducts_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName != "Page")
    {
        int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView g2 = (GridView)gvProducts.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("GridView2");

        if (e.CommandName == "Details")
        {
            int customerId = (int)this.gvProducts.DataKeys[rowindex]["sID"];

            gvProducts.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("btn_Show").Visible = false;

            sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM `doTable` ");
            sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
            sql += String.Format(" sID IN ('{0}') ", customerId);

            g2.DataSource = GetData(sql);
            g2.DataBind();
            g2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            g2.Visible = false;
            gvProducts.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("btn_Show").Visible = true;

        }
    }
}


protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = gvProducts.PageIndex;

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Prev":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = gvProducts.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/bot_back.gif"
                    CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/bot_back2.gif"
                    CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" />
                Page
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="ddl_Class"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLPages_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                of
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/bot_next.gif"
                    CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="/aspnet/img/bot_next2.gif"
                    CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page" />
            </PagerTemplate>
```

**Edit #01**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Show" runat="server"
       CommandName="Details"
       CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What input are you actually sending to your method? Can you give an example of a case where it crashes? For now it seems like rowindex is either returning -1 from clicking previous on the first page or is too big because your targeted row does not exist yet?

Comment: What value do you get in `rowindex` variable? Which button in the GridView you are clicking to execute `gvProducts_RowCommand` code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The value of `rowindex` is always correct because I have added in `gvProducts_RowCommand` the `Response.Write(rowindex); Response.End();`. The button in GridView for execute please see **Edit #01** in my first question. Thank you.

Comment: You will not get exception if rowindex value is  correct. So you need to observe its value and share it here.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have exception on `GridView g2 = (GridView)gvProducts.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("GridView2");` and not in `rowindex`

Comment: You need to read https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-array-indexoutofrange-exception/amp/ to understand why you are getting this exception.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Your link no talks about gridview ...

Comment: The link talks about collection and gvProducts.Rows is a collection. If you are trying to access element of collection using index value which is out of range of the collection size you will get this exception.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks but I'm not that expert for something like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need replace this :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Show" runat="server"
       CommandName="Details"
       CommandArgument='<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

With :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_Show" runat="server"
       CommandName="Details"
       CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```